# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. For pandas.concat

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have tried many ways to concatenate a list of DataFrames together but am continuously getting the error message "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part."

At the moment the list only contains two elements, both of them being DataFrames. They do have different columns in places but i didn't think this would be an issue. At the moment I have:
`df_year_stats = pd.concat(yearStats, axis = 0, ignore_index = True).reset_index(drop=True)`

I don't think the dataframes have any lists in them but that is the only plausible solution I have thought of so far, if so how would I go about checking for these.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

edit code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

course_df = pd.read_csv("dg_course_table.csv")

soup = bs(requests.get('https://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.ROTT_INQ.html').text, 'html.parser')

tabs = soup.find('div',attrs={'class','tabbable-head clearfix hidden-small'})
subStats = tabs.find_all('a')

# creating lists of tab and link, and removing the first and last
tab_links = []
tab_names = []
for subStat in subStats:
 tab_names.append(subStat.text)
 tab_links.append(subStat.get('href'))

tab_names = tab_names[1:-2] #potentially remove other areas here- points/rankings and streaks
tab_links = tab_links[1:-2]

# creating empty lists
stat_links = []
all_stat_names = []

# looping through each tab and extracting all of the stats URL's, along with the corresponding stat name. 
for link in tab_links:
    page2 = 'https://www.pgatour.com' + str(link)
    req2 = requests.get(page2)
    soup2 = bs(req2.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # find correct part of html code
    stat = soup2.find('section',attrs={'class','module-statistics-off-the-tee clearfix'})
    specificStats = stat.find_all('a')
  
    for stat in specificStats:
        stat_links.append(stat.get('href'))
        all_stat_names.append(stat.text)

s_asl = pd.Series(stat_links, index = all_stat_names )

s_asl = s_asl.drop(labels='show more')

s_asl = s_asl.str[:-4]

tourn_links = pd.Series([],dtype=('str'))

df_all_stats = []


req4 = requests.get('https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/stats/stat.120.y2014.html')
soup4 = bs(req4.text, 'html.parser')
stat = soup4.find('select',attrs={'aria-label':'Available Tournaments'})
htm = stat.find_all('option')
for h in htm: #finding all tournament codes for the given year
 z = pd.Series([h.get('value')],index=[h.text])
 tourn_links = tourn_links.append(z)

yearStats = []
count = 0

for tournament in tourn_links[0:2]: # create stat tables for two different golf tournaments
 print(tournament)    
 df1 = []
 df_labels = []
     
 for r in range(0,len(s_asl)): #loop through all stat links adding the corresponding stat to that tounaments df
  try:
   link = 'https://www.pgatour.com'+s_asl[r]+'y2014.eon.'+tournament+'.html'
   web = pd.read_html(requests.get(link).text)
   table = web[1].set_index('PLAYER NAME')
   df1.append(table)
   df_labels.append(s_asl.index[r])
  except:
   print("empty table")
 try:
  df_tourn_stats = pd.concat(df1,keys=df_labels,axis=1)
  df_tourn_stats.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
  df_tourn_stats.insert(1,'Tournament Name',tourn_links.index[count])
  df_tourn_stats.to_csv(str(count) + ".csv")
        
  df_tourn_stats = df_tourn_stats.loc[:,~df_tourn_stats.columns.duplicated()].copy()
        
  yearStats.append(df_tourn_stats)
 except:
  print("NO DATA")
 count= count + 1
 
 #combine the stats of the two different tournaments into one dataframe       
df_year_stats = pd.concat(yearStats, axis = 0, ignore_index = True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: You mentioned a line of code, without data context. I cannot run your line of code and see the identical result that you see. You want me to help you even though I cannot reproduce your issue. Please help me to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @J_H Sorry, understandable. The code does take a few minutes to run as it is scraping quite a large quantity of data but I hope I have formatted it in a way that is understandable above.

Comment: You are explaining that (A.) the behavior observed is clearly impossible, yet (B.) I observed such behavior, please help me to understand it. Well, such a journey starts with small steps, not with large quantities of unseen data. Doesn't matter if you're explaining the behavior to yourself or to me. You still need to distill it down to a conveniently reproducible test case. It takes work. Recommend you get started on it. The more (small!) datasets you run through your unit test, the better you will understand it, and that will help you explain it to SO folks.